# Trigger event called by an another class

Tags: c#, events, mvvm, triggers

I want to triggered my event when my UI call my class, life this :

[image]

In my UI i call my class ScanClass with a string parameter

```
ScanMessage scn = new ScanMessage(message);
```

In my class ScanMessage i made this :

```
public class ScanMessage
{
    public delegate void OnScanMessageReceived(string message);

    public ScanMessage()
    {
    }

    public ScanMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageReceived(message);
    }

    public event OnScanMessageReceived MessageReceived;
}
```

And i made this in my FirstViewModel

```
public FirstViewModel()
    {
        var scanMessage = new ScanMessage();
        scanMessage.MessageReceived += ScanMessage_MessageReceived;
    }

    private void ScanMessage_MessageReceived(string message)
    {
        //Do something
    }
```

Well, if i post here, it's because i have a problem and i can't fix it without help !

Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is the instance of `ScanMessage` is different. UI class has different instance and VM has different instance. Hence raising event on one instance is not being heard in other one.

If all your `ScanMessage` needs to do is to broadcast event, you can have its singleton instance

```
public class ScanMessage
{
    public delegate void OnScanMessageReceived(string message);

    private static ScanMessage _scanMessage = new ScanMessage();
    private ScanMessage()
    {
    }

    public static ScanMessage Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _scanMessage;
        }
    }
    public void BroadCastMessage(string message)
    {
        MessageReceived(message);
    }

    public event OnScanMessageReceived MessageReceived;
}
```

And then from UI you can call like

```
ScanMessage.Instance.BroadCastMessage(message);
```

and in your VM you can

```
public FirstViewModel()
{
    ScanMessage.Instance.MessageReceived += ScanMessage_MessageReceived;
}

private void ScanMessage_MessageReceived(string message)
{
    //Do something
}
```